# Display Events in JCal Pro Calendar on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have a Joomla! website, that uses [JCal Pro](https://www.joomlashack.com/joomla-extensions/jcal/) to display the calendar.

Now, in my Google calendar, I want to import the JCal calendar into it. In other words, I want to display the contents of JCal Pro in my Google Calendar.

Whenever the JCal calendar is updated, the changes must be automatically reflected in Google Calendar.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can it output data in iCal format?

Comment: @Al, yes it can. But I want dynamic updates. So manually exporting it and reimporting it just won't cut it.

Comment: If you've got a URL for the iCal output, then it's trivial to add to Google Calendar. If it doesn't, well, then you're up a proverbial creek.

You might be better off importing Google Calendar into JCal.

Comment: Looks like it [might be supported in the future](http://anything-digital.com/forum/extension/jcal-pro/2956-google-cal-sync.html?p=1#p18393).